# Google Mock: obtain AssertionResult from EXPECT_THAT

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I'm trying to write a google-test utility function which performs some setup steps base on it's input arguments and finally compares the contents of two containers irrespective of order. I would then like to return a `::testing::AssertionResult` from this function based on whether the container contents are equal.

For the comparison itself I would like to use functionalities provided by google-mock in order to avoid errors in my own test-code and reduce developement overhead. Something like the following would work:

```
EXPECT_THAT(actual_container,
    testing::UnorderedElementsAreArray(expected_container))
    << "Container content equal.";
```

The trouble with this is that I'm not sure if it is even possible to
obtain an `AssertionResult` which can be returned from a function in a similar manner.

Does anyone have a solution to this or a suggestion for an alternative approach?